# using Code coverage using QUnit and Teamcity

Tags: javascript, teamcity, code-coverage, qunit

Actually I am in the process to run my javascript code on teamcity using QUnit+ phantomjs.
(using this link as reference:http://thomasardal.com/running-qunit-tests-on-teamcity/)
And at least the execution of my tests using phantomjs looks ok on my local machine so in someway I am happy :). But that is not all what i want to do, I would like to add code coverage to my javascript tests and run it from our Teamcity server. is there some way to do that? jscoverage is an alternative?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As to TeamCity side of the question, [here are some notes](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/How+To...#HowTo...-IntegratingwithReporting/MetricTools) in the doc on how external coverage results can be integrated into TeamCity.